# Bootstrap 3 Form not aligning correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a form group but they are not aligned correctly with Bootstrap 3.

I am trying to aligned them vertically. This is giving me a nightmare so need some of your help

Please see below for screen shot

[image: Form not alligning]

Below is the code for the form

```
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- left column -->
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="text-center">
              <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
              <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

              <input type="file" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- edit form column -->
          <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
<!--            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
              <a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a> 
              <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
              This is an <strong>.alert</strong>. Use this to show important messages to the user.
            </div> -->
            <h3>Personal info</h3>

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Jane">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Bishop">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Company:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="janesemail@gmail.com">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <div class="ui-select">
                    <select id="user_time_zone" class="form-control">
                      <option value="Hawaii">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
                      <option value="Alaska">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
                      <option value="Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Arizona">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>
                      <option value="Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" selected="selected">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Indiana (East)">(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="janeuser">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                  <span></span>
                  <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

my css sheet

```
/* CSS declarations go here */

.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon{
    background: white !important; 
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control{
    border-right:0; 
    box-shadow:0 0 0; 
    border-color:#ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button{
    border:0;
    background:transparent;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}



* {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.bg{
    background: url(fundog.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;


}
.help{
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 300px;

}

.spread{margin-bottom: 0px;}

body {

    /* set this equal to navbar's height */
}

.usp{
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.profile{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: i think the bootstrap class inside your form-group should add up equal 12?
because i found that you are using col-lg-3 and col-lg-8

Comment: Hi so i need to use col-lg-3 and col-lg-9?

Comment: @Tomchan yeah ... you need to use `col-lg-3` and `col-lg-9` and also put column classes on `div` **not** on `label`s

Comment: Yup,  u may try that to see how is the result look like

Comment: @Katrin that's not required. specifying a 3 and and 8 just says "use the first 11 of 12 columns". That remaining column just wouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own css is causing problems:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Specifically, your combination of `float:none` and `display: table-cell`.  Remove them and let bootstrap lay them out how it normally does.

Also not sure about setting everything's margin to zero.  Like it or not, Bootstrap utilises negative margins to correctly layout some of its classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated version that has your header, and all of the columns inline vertically.

http://www.bootply.com/b38G8GZgjw

Here's the code in case bootply is not available:

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- left column -->
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="text-center">
              <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
              <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

              <input type="file" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- edit form column -->
          <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
<!--            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
              <a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a> 
              <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
              This is an <strong>.alert</strong>. Use this to show important messages to the user.
            </div> -->
            <div class="row">
            <h3 class="col-lg-3 text-right">Personal info</h3>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Jane">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Bishop">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Company:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="janesemail@gmail.com">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <div class="ui-select">
                    <select id="user_time_zone" class="form-control">
                      <option value="Hawaii">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
                      <option value="Alaska">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
                      <option value="Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Arizona">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>
                      <option value="Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" selected="selected">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
                      <option value="Indiana (East)">(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="janeuser">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input class="form-control" type="password" value="11111122333">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
                  <span></span>
                  <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it s still not working properly, maybe my current CCS sheet is messing it up.